# Flowable does not recover from exception with onExceptionResumeNext

Tags: java, rx-java2, web3-java

I am using web3j to listen to live event coming from the blockchain(based on rx-java2 ver 2.2.21 that comes packed with the web3j)

it is working ok but I have an issue,

I would like to keep the live subscription even on exception, I implemented it like so:

```
  web3j.ethLogFlowable(ethFilter)
                .onExceptionResumeNext(Flowable.empty())
                .subscribe(this::produceMessage);
```

I tested it in a unitest using  the following test (`Log` is the class that should return from `ethLogFlowable`):

```
 Log log = mock(Log.class);
 doReturn(Flowable.just(log, "test", log), Flowable.just(log, log)).when(web3j).ethLogFlowable(any(EthFilter.class));
```

as you can see, the `"test"` string will cause an exception and it does, the problem is that it is stopping the stream and not continue to next as I would expect:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.Log (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.Log is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onError(LambdaSubscriber.java:79)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:69)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextSubscriber.onNext(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:80)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray$ArraySubscription.fastPath(FlowableFromArray.java:132)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray$BaseArraySubscription.request(FlowableFromArray.java:88)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.SubscriptionArbiter.setSubscription(SubscriptionArbiter.java:99)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:69)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray.subscribeActual(FlowableFromArray.java:38)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14935)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext.subscribeActual(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:40)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14935)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14872)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14760)
    at com.citi.nexus.ethereumadaptor.events.EthEventListener.subscribe(EthEventListener.java:120)
    at com.citi.nexus.ethereumadaptor.events.EthEventListener.startLiveSubscription(EthEventListener.java:90)
    at com.citi.nexus.ethereumadaptor.events.EthEventListener.startSubscription(EthEventListener.java:79)
    at com.citi.nexus.ethereumadaptor.events.EthEventListener.executeOnApplicationReady(EthEventListener.java:62)
    at com.citi.nexus.ethereumadaptor.events.EthEventListenerTest.executeOnApplicationReadySyncLiveWithError(EthEventListenerTest.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.Log (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.Log is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:65)
    ... 83 more
```

I can add an `onError` method, but stream will still stop after I would like it to continue

can someone explained to me what am I doing wrong?

P.S my solution is to recreate the flowable inside the onException it does work but it is less elegant I think

Comment: If an exception enters into RxJava, that will stop the sequence. `onErrorResumeNext` is there to turn that exception into some other sequence. You have to suppress the exception so RxJava doesn't know about it or you have to use one of the `retry` operators to resubscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnErrorNotImplementedException is thrown because you've not implemented the onError handler, as stated in the message.

basically, instead of

```
  web3j.ethLogFlowable(ethFilter)
                .onExceptionResumeNext(Flowable.empty())
                .subscribe(this::produceMessage);
```

you could have:

```
  web3j.ethLogFlowable(ethFilter)
                .onExceptionResumeNext(Flowable.empty())
                .subscribe(
                      this::produceMessage,
                      error -> { 
                            // log some message ...
                            error.printStackTrace();
                      });
```

see. http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Flowable.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer-